# AddActorLocalRotation C++ relative rotation issue

Tags: unreal-engine5

I have c++ code which randomly selects 2 direction to rotate a cube.

```
        {
    if(clicked)
    {
        if(rot_left==-1)
        {
            rot_left=90;
            direction=rand() % 2;
        }else
        if( rot_left>0)
        {
            if(direction==1)
                AddActorLocalRotation(FRotator(0, 0, 1));
            else
                AddActorLocalRotation(FRotator(1, 0, 0));
            rot_left--;
        }
        else
        {
            clicked=false;
            rot_left=-1;
        }
    }
        }
```

However sometimes the cube rotates around the middle axis. I think this is due to previous rotation causing a relative axis change.
Any ideas how to prevent it rotating around the middle axis?

I have tried google obvs, i tried changing to vector3 but it requires a frotator